# Ribbon added via VBA code takes time to show up in the excel... looks like a refresh issue?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

After adding the VBA code to add a custom ribbon, i see that it takes time to show up in the tool bar. The VBA code to create ribbon is called in our Workbook open event.

```
    Sub LoadCustRibbon(sDummy)
        Dim hFile As Long
        Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

        hFile = FreeFile
        user = Environ("Username")
        path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
        fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

        ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     <mso:qat>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "       <mso:sharedControls>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "           <mso:button id='RefreshRow' label='RefreshRow' imageMso='Refresh' onAction='RefreshRow'/>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "           <mso:button id='RefreshSheet' label='RefreshSheet' imageMso='RefreshAll' onAction='RefreshSheet'/>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "       </mso:sharedControls>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     </mso:qat>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:tab id='RefreshTab' label='Refresh Scores' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:group id='RefreshScoreGrp' label='Refresh Scores' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "             <mso:button id='RefreshRow' label='RefreshRow' imageMso='Refresh' onAction='RefreshRow'/>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "             <mso:button id='RefreshSheet' label='RefreshSheet' imageMso='RefreshAll' onAction='RefreshSheet'/>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

        ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

        Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
        Print #hFile, ribbonXML
        Close hFile
    End Sub
```

I expect that when open the workbook the ribbon should show up immediately. Not sure what I am missing. I used this code snippet from stackoverflow thread though.

Comment: Why u do not edit the inner XML in your Excel File (so only the file will see the new ribbon) , and not the Ribbon from Office excel (who impacts in the application)?

Comment: That's right. I want the ribbon to be visible only when this document is opened as the ribbon uses inbuilt private macros that is not exposed to other workbooks. I did have a temporary solution to make the ribbon visible by having a msgbox right after loading the custom ribbon. Thats only a temp solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a temporary solution by adding a MsgBox right after the LoadCustRibbon in Workbook_Open event. But I would like to have the ribbon shown with out it. Any help?

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Call LoadCustRibbon("")
        MsgBox "Please enable macros! Also, go through the 'Read Me' tab on how to use this workbook"
    End Sub
```